# Under what circumstances can time in time.h fail?

Tags: c, posix

The `time` function in the header `time.h` is defined by POSIX to return a `time_t` which can, evidently, be a signed int or some kind of floating point number.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/time

The function, however, returns `(time_t)(-1)` on error.

Under what circumstances can `time` fail?

Based on the signature, `time_t time( time_t *arg )` it seems like the function shouldn't allocate, so that strikes one potential cause of failure.

Comment: Why on Earth would you use "cppreference.com" as a source for C documentation? Yes, C++ and C are *related*, but still not the same. For POSIX stuff, use the [POSIX.1-2008](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/functions.html) standard. For C and POSIX functions (excluding most of the silly `_s` functions Microsoft managed to stuff into C11, that nobody outside Windows will ever use), use the [Linux Man Pages Online](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/dir_all_alphabetic.html); most pages contain a *Conforming To* section, which describes the relevant standards for the function.

Comment: Their coverage of C-specific stuff is pretty good and the page references the relevant standards. Noted though, I’ll use a better source next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `time()` function is actually defined by ISO, to which POSIX mostly defers except it may place further restrictions on behaviour and/or properties (like an eight-bit byte, for example).

And, since the ISO C standard doesn't specify *how* `time()` may fail<sup>(a)</sup>, the list of possibilities is not limited in *any* way:

- One way in which it *may* fail is in the embedded arena. It's quite possible that your C program may be running on a device with no real-time clock or other clock hardware (even a counter), in which case no time would be available.
- Or maybe the function detects *bad* clock hardware that's constantly jumping all over the place and is therefore unreliable.
- Or maybe you're running in a real-time environment where accesses to the clock hardware are time-expensive so, if it detects you're doing it too often, it decides to start failing so your code can do what it's meant to be doing :-)

The possibilities are literally infinite and, of course, I mean 'literally' in a figurative sense rather than a literal one :-)

---

POSIX itself calls out *explicitly* that it will fail if it detects the value won't fit into a `time_t` variable:

> The `time()` function may fail if: `[EOVERFLOW]` The number of seconds since the Epoch will not fit in an object of type `time_t`.

---

And, just on your comment:

> Based on the signature, `time_t time( time_t *arg )`, it seems like the function shouldn't allocate.

You need to be circumspect about this. Anything not mandated by the standards is totally open to interpretation. For example, I can envisage a bizarre implementation that allocates space for an NTP request packet to go out to `time.nist.somewhere.org` so as to ensure all times are up to date even *without* an NTP client :-)

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In fact, it doesn't even specify what the *definition* of `time_t` is so it's unwise to limit it to an integer or floating point value, it could be the string representation of the number of fortnights since the big bang :-) All it requires is that it's usable by the other `time.h` functions and that it can be cast to `-1` in the event of failure.

POSIX *does* state that it represents number of seconds (which ISO doesn't) but places no other restrictions on it.

Comment: ISO C specifies that `time_t` and `clock_t` must be "real types capable of representing times" -- i.e., `time_t` must be either integer (signed or unsigned) or floating-point. (It can't be a complex type.) But it says nothing about *how* it represents time; it could use `20180302204129` to represent the current time (as I'm typing this). POSIX imposes some stricter requirements.

Answer (score 4):

I can imagine several causes:

1. the hardware timer isn't available, because the hardware doesn't support it.
2. the hardware timer just failed (hardware error, timer registers cannot be accessed for some reason)
3. `arg` is not null, but points to some illegal location. Instead of crashing, some implementations could detect an illegal pointer (or catch the resulting SEGV) and return an error instead.
4. in the provided link "Implementations in which time_t is a 32-bit signed integer (many historical implementations) fail in the year 2038.". So after 1<<31 seconds since the epoch (1/1/1970), time return value overflows (well, that is, if the hardware doesn't mask the problem by silently overflowing as well).

Comment: POSIX says `time()` fails with `EOVERFLOW` if "The number of seconds since the Epoch will not fit in an object of type **`time_t`**".

Comment: you mean the 2038 C bug then.

Comment: Yes, and variations of it. On 64-bit systems, there might be a Y292277026596 bug. Other systems have used epochs other than 1970.